# Using loop to iterate all variables in sass and trying to update value of them

Tags: sass

I have this piece of code. Is there a way how to make work the last part where I'm trying to assign css variable call to sass variables? I can't figure it out. How to dynamically work with sass variable names.

```sass
@use "sass:meta"
@use "sass:map"

@use "../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/derived-variables" as dv
@use "../node_modules/bulmaswatch/cyborg/variables" as v

@function g($key)
  @return map.get(meta.module-variables(dv), $key)

// create css variables for light theme
\:root
  @each $key, $value in meta.module-variables(v)
    @if map.has-key(meta.module-variables(dv), $key)
      $tmp: g($key)
      --#{$key}: #{$tmp}

// create css variables override for dark theme
\:root.dark
  @each $key, $value in meta.module-variables(v)
    --#{$key}: #{$value}

// assign css variables calls to sass variables -- need help with this!
@each $key, $value in meta.module-variables(v)
  #{$key}: var(--#{$key})
```

Because I don't want to change code of framework I'm using where sass variables are used. And also I don't want to manually list all sass variables and assign them css var().